# Changing color of item in table depending on data value

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

My goal is to have the items in `$row['status']` to change to red if value is OFF and green if value is ON. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM enclosure ORDER BY computer ASC");
echo "<table id='table' align='center' border='1' cellspacing='3' cellpadding='3' width='75%'>
<tr>
    <td align='left'><b>Enclosure Name</b></td>
    <td align='left'><b>Screen Status</b></td>
    <td align='left'><b>Time Screen in status</b>
    </td><td align='left'><b>Temperature of Enclosure</b></td>
    </td><td align='left'><b>Incoming Voltage</b></td>
</tr>"; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    $row['voltage'] = $row['voltage'] /1000;
    echo "<tr>
        <td align='left'>".$row['computer']."</td>
        <td align='left'>".$row['status']."</td>
        <td align='left'>".gmdate("H:i:s",$row['length'])."</td>
        <td align='left'>".$row['temp']."</td>
        <td align='left'>".$row['voltage']."</td>
        </tr>";         
}
mysqli_close($dbc);
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "5";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevlishOne's answer is correct, however you should also consider setting the class of the `<td>` rather than the color. If you're formatting desires become more sophisticated than red/green (e.g. transitions) or if this is or become a larger chunk of code you will appreciate having the styles shifted out to a css file. It's generally considered a good idea.

**ADDITION:**

You asked for a simple version using classes:

```
echo "<td align='left' class='STATUS" . $row['status']  . "'>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
```

This uses classes named STATUSON and STATUSOFF so you could use a css stylesheet with

```
STATUSON {
color: green;
}

STATUSOFF {
color: red;
}
```

Obviously, you can add more formatting to each of those classes if that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That is what i was trying to do at first but couldn't figure out how. could you give me an example on how that would look

Comment: I added an example above.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<td align='left'>".$row['status']."</td>
```

To:

```
echo "<td align='left' style='color:" . ($row['status'] == "OFF" ? "red" : "green") . "'>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
```